Unexpected CSS behavior when using React Aria Checkbox inside a container with combination of max width, auto margin and overflow hidden
I've raised issue on the React Spectrum GitHub in #7108.
An unexpected behavior on the rendered document where the React Aria Checkbox contained in a container that resides outside the container max height bound still take space in the page that cause additional blank space after the container rendered. Such issue occurred when the container have CSS properties of max-width, margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto and overflow: hidden, and containing overflowing React Aria Checkbox, but not with other component such React Aria TextField. Can someone explain the reason this is happening? is it a bug that should be reported to React Aria maintainer? As for the workaround, I use the React Aria Hooks as it's included in the replication code repo.
Here's the link to replication code. The instruction on starting the web app on local machine documented in the README of the project.
Here's the snippet of the container CSS,
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

Here's the comparison of the rendered page with same CSS properties but containing different component (React Aria Checkbox and TextField),
With Checkbox

With TextField

And here's the code snippet of the React component implementation,
import { Checkbox, CheckboxGroup, Input, Label, TextField } from 'react-aria-components'
import './App.css'
import WorkaroundChecbox from './components/WorkaroundCheckbox'

export default function App({ type }: { type: 'normal' | 'anomaly' | 'workaround' }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="filler">Filler</div>
      <CheckboxGroup className="checkbox-group">
        {
          Array.from(Array(200).keys())
            .map((_, index) => (
              <>
              {type === 'normal' &&  (
                <TextField>
                  <Label>{index}</Label>
                  <Input />
                </TextField>
              )}
              {type === 'anomaly' &&  (
                  <Checkbox>{index}</Checkbox>
                )}
              {type === 'workaround' &&  (
                  <WorkaroundChecbox>{index}</WorkaroundChecbox>
                )}
              </>
            ))
          }
      </CheckboxGroup>
    </div>
  )
}

!Update
The root cause was spotted, it was due to the usage of VisuallyHidden wrapper component in the following code. I managed to replicate the behavior by adding the VisuallyHidden wrapper into my custom checkbox component included in the issue replication repo. Waiting for the maintainer update on the raised GitHub issue.

Can you put a minimal reproducible code snippet into your question. A link to your github repo wont help much. Nobody wants to crawl through tons of code just to find the error.

@MrJoky added code snippet. Btw, i think this is a bug from the React Aria component lib since the workaround using the React Aria hook instead of the component works. Will raise a bug in their GitHub.
